# Gmail API non date query not returning same number of results as the Gmail web interface

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-client

I've got something odd going on with the gmail web UI search versus the gmail api search.  I've got a test search where q=test .  No date filters or anything.  Via the web UI I get a ton of results ( over 50 ).  However, when I try the same exact query in the gmail api it only returns 2.  See screenshots below.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

From the gmail web UI of gmail
[image: From the web ui of gmail]

From the gmail api
[image: From the gmail api]

Also, just as a note, I've got threads turned off on the web ui, so its not a mismatch between messages and threads.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are you sure you used the same email account when trying the Web UI and the API?

Comment: Yeah, I'm 100% positive its the same account.